# Google Cloud Functions Build failed: function.js does not exist; Error ID: 7485c5b6

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions

I generated a demo express server using these steps:

- `npm install -g express-generator`
- `express myExpressApp --view pug`

Needless to say, the app runs fine on my local machine (`npm start`)

I then pushed the code to Cloud Source Repositories

Then deploy to Google Cloud Functions through their web app

What am I missing?
[image]

Source codes of my generated demo app:

/myExpressApp/app.js

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

/myExpressApp/routes/index.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

[image]

**Final updates**

I added the following as suggested by Abrar Hossain
app.js

```js
//...
module.exports = app;

exports.app = functions.http.onRequest(app);
module.exports = { app };
```

package.json

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "functions-framework --target=company"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^1.7.1",
```

But the issue persists

Entry point is set as "app"
[image]

Comment: If app.js is the entry point of your function then it should export a Firebase function: `exports.app = functions.http.onRequest(app);` where `functions` is a reference to `firebase-functions` which need to imported into your app.js script.

Comment: No, why would you think so @YeriPelona?

Comment: hello @ericn did you find a solution for this issue? I'm encountering the same symptom and I'm clueless

Comment: No @ImanZarrabian, my solution is to use another technology (Springboot + Heroku)

Comment: it's not you.  if for some reason you didnt put the entry point in correctly (defaults to helloWorld) at the start, you need to start from scratch.  changing the entry point should work but doesnt.  i noticed this when i changed the code to inline and created a new exports.app with just res.status(200).send('OK');  even that failed. the same code in a new function worked.

Answer (score 4):

In short, during deployment, you have to specify the name of the JS function you want to use as GCP Cloud function, it is specified `--entry-point` flag. More information [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/repo) (pls, do look at the flags sections). `app` in your case. If you provide the deployment script, I can point you to the exact spot

Long answer - the common misconception is that a GCP Cloud functions = Express app. It is not. Although under the hood they might use express and you might event request certain behavior via configuration. In reality, for GCP it is just a JS function, nothing more or less. No routers or anything like that. If you want to test it locally, use [Functions Framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs). You can get further details in [my post](https://medium.com/@neatnerd/google-cloud-functions-testing-part-1-af265b5e42a2)

Comment: Thanks but there's no deployment script. This is absolutely beginner step 1 stuff here. The Functions Framework repo is useful. It means the hello world index.js by Google Cloud Functions is not plain Javascript, it's based on that framework which bakes in Express JS!

Answer (score 1):

Export your app like this:

```
module.exports = { app };
```

And add your app.js entry to package.json:

```
"main": "app.js",
```

Answer (score 1):

I kept running the deploy script from the wrong directory and this happened, so easy fix was to actually `cd` into the project directory.

Must be a pretty silly error, because I didn't find much advice online. But, I guess until you know how to interpret feedback, it's a bit of mystery. I'm a newbie at the Cloud Console, started a tutorial one day, came back to it the next (after reopening the website), opened the terminal to deploy, and didn't noticed that I was in the `/home/${USER}` dir, and not the project dir.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error and the problem was due to deploying the code on the base folder and not on the project folder. To show the folders type: ls and then move to the right folder using: cd NameOfYourFolder  .Repeat the deployment instruction and that should work.
The other solution is to check on your package.json file that the name of the function is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had firebase functions set that was created by the *firebase cli* with the *Typescript* option and I found not only this but some other issues that were preventing its deploy or execution. The only way I got it working was by completely removing the functions folder and running the *firebase cli functions* setup again `firebase init functions` but this time choosing the **Javascript** option.

A few other things to keep in mind:

- Use *CommonJS* imports instead of *ES6* e.g. `const gcipCloudFunctions = require("gcip-cloud-functions")`
- Run `npm install` in your functions folder if it wasn't already
- **Deploy firebase functions before you deploy your gcloud one** `firebase deploy --only  functions`
- Deploy your gcloud function `gcloud functions deploy <your function name> --trigger-http --runtime=nodejs14 --verbosity=debug`
- If deploy works but it doesn't run, have a look at your runtime logs by just running `gcloud functions logs read <your function name>` or via the [GCloud UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/logs?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024-01 my best guess is, something is wrong with
Cloud Function, especially with the "directory with source code" option and the default JS entrypoint.

I had to move code (at least `package.json` and entrypoint JS) to repo root, and un-specify that option, to successfully deploy my Function to work today. I also renamed the entrypoint JS to `function.js` but this may not be necessary.

I don't have a complete proof chain, but when the Cloud Function is created with terraform, `repo_source.dir` is basically confirmed to not work: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/11408 .