# Getting function.js does not exist error when deploying 1st gen cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, github-webhook

I am writing a simple helloWorld function in a node.js(v16) app that I want to deploy using the 1st gen Google Cloud Functions (I want to eventually use GitHub Webhooks to deploy code). I keep getting this error:

`Build failed: function.js does not exist; Error ID: 7485c5b6`

This is my code:

index.js

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const got = require('got');
const url = require('url');

const settings = require('settings.json');

/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "got": "^12.5.2",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  }
}
```

settings.json

```
{
  "secretToken": "webhook_token",
  "accessToken": "github access token",
}
```

This app folder also contains a `package-lock.json` file and a folder for `node_modules`.

What am I missing here? Why do I keep getting the error `Build failed: function.js does not exist; Error ID: 7485c5b6`?

I have deployed it using the UI using this method: `ZIP from Cloud Storage` and also tried deploying using this command:
`gcloud functions deploy helloWorld --runtime nodejs16 --entry-point=index --trigger-http --stage-bucket bucket-name`

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65600181/google-cloud-functions-build-failed-function-js-does-not-exist-error-id-7485c

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, yes, tried those solutions but still facing the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this because I was compressing a folder with the files. What I needed to do was to highlight just the files and then select "compress".

Additionally you need to make sure your exported function name matches your `entry_point` parameter value if you're using Terraform.

google_cloudfunctions_function Terraform

`entry_point           = "exampleFunctionName"`

index.js export

`exports.exampleFunctionName = (event, context) => {`